# Pass current SKScene Instance Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How would I go about passing the current instance of a scene to another class?

For example:

**Scene 1: BLUE BOX ---> Scene 2: Edit Box to Red ---> Call current scene ---> RED BOX**

Before, I was presenting a scene every time by setting a statement. But, later I found that this was actually creating a new instance every time and my changes would not get applied. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think a different approach of storing all the changes to a seperate swift file to create a data object and applying it for the next scene.

```
class Square {

    //MARK: Properties

    static var Color: String = "Blue"
    static var Height: CGFloat = 4
    static var Width: CGFloat = 4
}
```

Set it Square.Color = "Red" and access it in the next scene. No need to create an instance of the class. (If you want to u can create a singleton)

But if it is a lot of changes I would not setup a scene but rather hide or remove the sprites accordingly.

Hope this was of any help.